# how to made combobox drop down change its list in correspondence to another combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am currently working on a small project for a business society in visual studio 2015 and SQL server. I have two comboboxes "AccountCode" and "AccountNo". I want to made "AccountNo" combobox to change its value in correspondence with the selection of a text from "AccountCode" drop down. But i get following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.

```
private void cmBxAccountCode_DataEntry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmBxAccountNo_DataEntry.ResetText();
        cmBxAccountNo_DataEntry.Refresh();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,ACCOUNTNO FROM  AccountHolder WHERE ACCOUNTCODE =" + cmBxAccountCode_DataEntry.Text, SQLConnection.con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        cmBxAccountNo_DataEntry.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cmBxAccountNo_DataEntry.DisplayMember = "ACCOUNTNO";
        cmBxAccountNo_DataEntry.ValueMember = "ID";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT ID,ACCOUNTNO FROM  AccountHolder WHERE ACCOUNTCODE ='" + cmBxAccountCode_DataEntry.Text  + "'"
```

But i strongly recommend you to use **Parameterized queries to avoid injection**; And also take selected value instead for `Text`( but it is according to the value in the database). The parameterized query will be like this :

```
// Code here
SqlCommand selectCommand=  new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,ACCOUNTNO FROM  AccountHolder WHERE ACCOUNTCODE =@accountCode", SQLConnection.con);
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@accountCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmBxAccountCode_DataEntry.Text;
// execute here
```

Comment: thanks @un-lucky. I got it and my problem solved! :)